# Cannot use data table.Find method after filling the data table using data adapter

Tags: c#, datatables, dataadapter

i have been using the disconnected model for my project. The issue is that i have used the data adapter .Fill command to fill my data table and it has been filled successfully but after filling the data table i cannot use the datatable.Find method to search data on the base of its primary key. Isn't data adapter suppose to assign everything including primary key after the fill command?
`//DataRow r = dt.Rows.Find(BO.RoomNo);` 
This, gives error when debugged says no primary key exists

Thus,i have to use a foreach loop instead

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
  if (BO.RoomNo == (int)r[1])
  {
    temp.RoomNo = (int)r[1];
    temp.Category = (string)r[2];
    temp.Price = (float)r[3];
    temp.Status = (string)r[4];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to set PrimaryKey property of DataTable as mentioned below,

```
//ID is primary key
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["ID"]};
```

Comment: How to do that? by clicking the up arrow?

Comment: There will be a tick mark below the up-down arrows  in my answer